# Call FLASK API into the same FLASK App HTML Page

Tags: python, html, api, flask

**PYTHON, FLASK, POSTGRES**

Created few API's in python using FLASK & designed a web page using HTML in same FLASK App,

on BASEURL/index -> opens web page where user enter some details
TASK - Need to save these details into Postgres DB

ON calling POST API to add user, Details get inserted into DB

Now, **inside Signle Flask APP**
I have a **Web page in HTML**  & a **function is used to insert entries into the DB**

Below is the function which i need to call on click of Submit button in Flask web page.

```
@endpoint.route("/adduser", methods=["POST"])
def createNewUser():
    data = request.values
    firstName = data.get('firstName')
    lastName = data.get('lastName')
    email = data.get('email')
    age = data.get('age')
    gender = data.get('gender')
    db.session.add(new_user)
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception:
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to add new user"}), 400
    return jsonify({"message": "User added successfully"}), 200
```

**NOTE**: Web page and function are of same app

**HELP**: How can i interact with this shown function on click of submit button in flask app web page

Comment: Did you try JS or want to implement it in python?

Comment: With JS i can use API URL directly & will create two code bases. but i am trying to use within the same flask app where API function is written